# ¿Cómo puedo almacenar variables en javascript y recibirlas en otra página con php?

Tags: php, javascript, json, variables

Estoy trabajando con un **api** y lo que hace es de que mando el **request**, crea una orden y al recibir obtengo los detalles de la orden en **json**. En la misma página no tengo problemas, visualizo los detalles de la orden con:

`document.getElementById('viewTransactionType').textContent = result.intent;`

solo un ejemplo y logro enviar las variables utilizando

`window.location.href =  "test_page.php?payer="+data;`

Al llegar en la segunda página en **php** donde deseo ordenar los detalles es donde no logro  obtener la información he intentado obtener los detalles con **get** y luego almacenarlos en variables **php** para ordenarlos e imprimirlos con **echo**, pero no despliega nada. Sin embargo visualizo la barra de direcciones y efectivamente, ahí están las variables que mandé de la página anterior con  `window.location.href` con los resultados que deseo, pero no logro desplegar en pantalla.

¿Alguien me podría ayudar?

Comment: Hola amigo antonio, bienvenido a stackoverflow en spanish, por favor revisa el [tour] y lee porfavor sobre [ask], para poder mejorar la pregunta, en tu caso,  lo digo porque falta un poco de fondo... son muy pocos datos pada dar una solucion acertiva (con datos me refiero a codigo), ademas el codigo no se encuentra correctamente formateado,  pero bueno... en eso te puedo ayudar,   saludos!

Answer (score 0):

En php obtienes el parámetro por get:

```
$_GET["payer"];
if(!empty($_GET["payer"])){
//Aquí va tu código
}
```

Inténtalo

Comment: muchas gracias , lo intentare ...

Answer (score 0):

hola Antonio por lo que veo no tienes problemas para llevar a cabo la consulta de método get en el lado de PHP. pero para confirmar te recomiendo que coloques este codigo en tu backend solo para confirmar que de este lado todo funciona

```
echo var_dump($_GET);
```

acá muestras todas la variables que estas pasando y sus valores con eso puedes depurar un poco. 
( TODO ANDA BIEN EN BACKEND )

ok entonces donde yo creo que esta tu error es en JavaScript veras windows.location.ref no funciona exactamente como quieres te recomiendo usar
`window.location.assign("https://tusitio.com/?payer.....");`

Comment: muchas gracias Alejandro por tu pronta respuesta efectivamente   al utilizar echo var_dump($_GET);   me da lo siguiente :   'payer' => string 'CAPTURE' (length=7)
  'test' => string 'COMPLETED' (length=9) indicando  que efectivamente deberia de poderlas recibir   y ahi es donde esta mi error las queria recibir normal como si fueran string pero las estaba recibiendo  en  array  ya solo  utilize   json_decode y listo ya las puedo  visualizar .... muchas  gracias....

Comment: estamos para ayudarnos, si puedes marcar la respuesta como definitiva me ayudarías tu a mi

Comment: recuerda cerrar la pregunta !